# Silex trigger 404 error inside match callback

Tags: php, symfony, exception, http-status-code-404, silex

I have this code, that match some routes coming from a json file:

```
    $this->app->match($routePattern, function(Request $request, \Silex\Application $app) use($routeIdent, $templateConfig) {

          //now here i need to check some conditions and, 
          //in case, trigger 404 error, but without redirect!!!!

          if($templateConfig['test'] === true){
             //----> TRIGGER 404
          }

    });
```

There is a way to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood your question correctly. You if you want to achieve 404 handling in the if? One solution would be returning a response right there. E.g. if you use use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response object and built in twig service you can do this like that:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response    

$this->app->match($routePattern, function(Request $request, \Silex\Application $app) use($routeIdent, $templateConfig) {

    if($templateConfig['test'] === true){
         //----> TRIGGER 404
        return new Response( $app['twig']->render('404.html.twig'), 404); 
    }
})
```

I hope that is what you were looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`abort()`](https://github.com/silexphp/Silex/blob/master/src/Silex/Application.php#L307):

```
return $app->abort(404);
```

The return is not neccessary as it throws, I just prefer to use it as a way of signalling it as an exit point.